# How to come up with an interval for this Big Oh Problem?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

This is from Discrete Mathematics and its Applications
[image]

I'am trying to use the interval method like what was shown in this example
[image]

Here is my work so far:

I noticed that when $x > 5$, $2^x > 17$, so
when $x > 5$, $2^x + 17 \leq  2^x + 2^x \leq 2*2^x$.
This shows that $2^x + 17$ is $O(2^x)$, because there exist constants $C = 2$ and $x_0 = 5$ such that when $x > 5$, $2^x + 17 < 2 * 2^x$.

The next step was to show that $O(2^x)$ is in $O(3^x)$.
To do this, I took a function $2^x$ that is in $O(2^x)$, and first observed that
when $x > 1$,  $2^x \leq  3^x$, so
$2^x$ is in $O(3^x)$ because there exist constants $C = 3$ and $x_0 = 1$ such that when $x > 1$, $2^x < 3^x$.

Did i do everything to show that $2^x + 17$ is $O(3^x)$? Is there a more efficient way to do this, to go straight to $O(3^x)$ and not $O(2^x)$ to $O(3^x)$ like I did ?

Comment: Is $x\in \mathbb{R}$ or $x\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @science doesn't say

Comment: You should be able to see that $C=2$ for $ x\geq 3 $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all $x>1$ we get
$$17+2^x \le 2^5+2^x \le 2^5\cdot 2^{x} \le 2^5 \cdot 3^{x}=O(3^x).$$
The notation of big O is useful for sufficiently large values of $x$, to give an idea of the order of magnitude of some function.

Comment: How did you get from $2^5$ + $2^x$ <=  $2^5$ * $2^x$. Just showing that for x = 2, 36 <= 128 and in the future, the multiplication will just grow faster?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $2 \cdot 2^x < 2 \cdot 3^x$ if $(\frac{3}{2})^x >1$, hence $\forall x>0$

Comment: Where did you get $(\frac{3}{2})^x$?

Comment: $3^x >2^x \to (\frac{3}{2})^x>1$

Comment: But they're of different bases